# Given that $k$ of the $n$ balls are blue, what is the conditional probability that the first ball chosen is blue?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A total of n balls are sequentially and randomly chosen, without
> replacement, from an urn containing $r$ red and $b$ blue balls. Given
> that $k$ of the $n$ balls are blue, what is the conditional
> probability that the first ball chosen is blue?

If we let A = first ball chosen is blue, B = k of n balls are blue, then I know that

$P(A,B) = \frac{b\binom{b-1}{k-1}\binom{r}{n-k}(n-1)!}{\binom{r+b}{n}n!}$

This makes sense: for the denominator, we pick a subset of size $n$ out of $r+b$ objects, and then multiply by $n!$ to obtain "order." With order, we have $b$ options for the first blue ball, then we choose $b-1$ blue balls out of k-1 blue balls, same with red, and we multiply $(n-1)!$ to add order.

I tried to obtain the answer for unordered but I think I got a wrong answer. I got

$P(A,B) = \frac{1\binom{b-1}{k-1}\binom{r}{n-k}}{\binom{r+b}{n}}$

Why is this wrong?

This counting stuff, so tricky ...

Comment: Both of your approaches are wrong.  Remember that the conditional probability that event $A$ occurs given that event $B$ has occurred is $$\Pr(A \mid B) = \frac{\Pr(A \cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$$  Your denominator should count the number of ways of selecting $n$ balls from $b$ blue and $r$ red balls if exactly $k$ of the selected balls are blue.  Your numerator should count the number of ways of selecting a blue ball with the first selection while selecting exactly $k$ blue balls when a total of $n$ balls are selected.

Comment: Please write an *INFORMATIVE* title.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Sorry for the confusion. I'm just trying to find the numerator; I already know the denominator. How's the 2 approaches for the numerator?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Also I know the answer is $k/n$ by symmetry but I'm intentionally doing it the long way to practice my counting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is just $\frac kn$.  Once you know that exactly $k$ of the $n$ balls you've drawn are blue, each possible permutation of those $n$ balls is equally likely, which means that each of the $n$ balls you've drawn is equally likely to be first.  Since $k$ of the $n$ balls are blue, that means the probability that the first ball is blue is $\frac kn$.

The numbers $r$ and $b$ affect the probability that you end up with $k$ blue balls in the first place, but once you know that's occurred, each permutation yielding that result is equally likely.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to solve the problem is to use the symmetry argument provided by Robert Shore.  Since exactly $k$ of the $n$ selected balls are blue, the probability that the first ball is blue is just $k/n$.

You indicated in the comments that you wished to use a counting argument.

By definition, the conditional probability that event $A$ occurs given that event $B$ occurs is
$$\Pr(A \mid B) = \frac{\Pr(A \cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$$
Your approach is wrong since you did not use this definition.

You defined event $B$ to the event that exactly $k$ of the $n$ balls selected without replacement from $b$ blue and $r$ red balls are blue.  The probability of selecting exactly $k$ of the $b$ blue balls when $n$ balls are selected from the $b + r$ available balls is
$$\Pr(B) = \frac{\dbinom{b}{k}\dbinom{r}{n - k}}{\dbinom{b + r}{n}}$$
since if we select $k$ of the $b$ blue balls, we must also select $n - k$ of the $r$ red balls in order to select $n$ of the $b + r$ available balls.

$A \cap B$ is the event that we select a blue ball on the first draw while selecting exactly $k$ blue balls in $n$ draws without replacement from the bag with $b$ blue and $r$ red balls.  Since $b$ of the $b + r$ balls in the urn are blue, the probability that the first ball selected is blue is
$$\Pr(A) = \frac{b}{b + r}$$
In order to obtain exactly $k$ blue balls after $n$ draws, we must then select $k - 1$ of the remaining $b - 1$ blue balls and $n - k$ of the remaining $r$ red balls while selecting $n - 1$ of the remaining $b + r - 1$ balls in the urn.  Hence,
$$\Pr(A \cap B) = \frac{b}{b + r} \cdot \frac{\dbinom{b - 1}{k - 1}\dbinom{r}{n - k}}{\dbinom{b + r - 1}{n - 1}}$$
Note that order matters here since the balls are selected sequentially.

Hence, the conditional probability that the first selected ball was blue given that exactly $k$ of the $n$ selected balls were blue is
\begin{align*}
\Pr(A \mid B) & = \frac{\Pr(A \cap B)}{\Pr(B)}\\[4 mm]
              & = \frac{\dfrac{b}{b + r} \cdot \frac{\dbinom{b - 1}{k - 1}\dbinom{r}{n - k}}{\dbinom{b + r - 1}{n - 1}}}{\frac{\dbinom{b}{k}\dbinom{r}{n - k}}{\dbinom{b + r}{n}}}\\[4 mm]
              & = \frac{\dfrac{b}{b + r} \cdot \frac{\dbinom{b - 1}{k - 1}}{\dbinom{b + r - 1}{n - 1}}}{\frac{\dbinom{b}{k}}{\dbinom{b + r}{n}}}\\
              & = \frac{\dfrac{b}{b + r} \cdot \frac{\dfrac{(b - 1)!}{(k - 1)!(b - k)!}}{\dfrac{(b + r - 1)!}{(n - 1)!(b + r - n)!}}}{\frac{\dfrac{b!}{k!(b - k)!}}{\dfrac{(b + r)!}{n!(b + r - n)!}}}\\[4 mm]
& = \frac{\frac{\dfrac{b!}{(k - 1)!(b - k)!}}{\dfrac{(b + r)!}{(n - 1)!(b + r - n)!}}}{\frac{\dfrac{b!}{k!(b - k)!}}{\dfrac{(b + r)!}{n!(b + r - n)!}}}\\[4 mm] 
& = \frac{\dfrac{b!}{(k - 1)!(b - k)!}}{\dfrac{(b + r)!}{(n - 1)!(b + r - n)!}} \cdot \frac{\dfrac{(b + r)!}{n!(b + r - n)!}}{\dfrac{b!}{k!(b - k)!}}\\[4 mm]
& = \frac{\dfrac{1}{(k - 1)!}}{\dfrac{1}{(n - 1)!}} \cdot \frac{\dfrac{1}{n!}}{\dfrac{1}{k!}}\\[4 mm] 
& = \frac{k!(n - 1)!}{(k - 1)!n!}\\[4 mm]
& = \frac{k}{n}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much for this very good explanation. Is it possible to solve for the probability of $A \cap B$ unordered? Or is this literally impossible because the problem asks that the first ball is blue - "first" automatically implies order.

Comment: The problem states that the balls are selected *sequentially*, which means the order of selection matters.  Since they are selected sequentially, we can refer to the first ball.